# What are categories in CPU usage profiler in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, io, visual-studio-2019, profiler

So, I ran a Visual Studio CPU usage profiler session for my application. After the end of it, in report I was seeing this:
[image: CPU usage report]

But what is "category"? Specifically, what does `IO: 59,2%` mean? Does it mean, that 59% of my application CPU usage was used to wait for I/O (then I should probably use asynchronous operations for this I/O)? Or is it just the usage of functions *related* to IO (functions that doing I/O somewhere, but not only it)? Or maybe something else?

Comment: I'm also keen to know this. Did you ever find out specifically what IO was in your application? It's 90% in mine which is a web crawler. So not sure if it's IO as in MySQL calls or HTTPS requests.

Comment: Same question over here, usually people refer to CPU-bound vs IO-bound, wherein IO encompasses disk access, so maybe the IO category refers to that?

Comment: Just adding my 2 cents. I have a purely CPU-bound application, but Visual Studio 2019 reports nearly 50% IO and 50% networking. The categorization seems really arbitrary, e.g. `std::_Sort_unchecked<int *,bool (__cdecl*)(int,int)` is categorized as Graphics | Kernel. Very weird and annoying.